# Exection architecture of a series of chained promises when page changes

Tags: javascript, promise, odata

I have series of OData calls which I make from JavaScript file (myfile.js) using Promises like shown below. The main entry point is the function MakePreferredCustomer(AccountNo). This function is called on load of a web page Page1.htm, which loads the JavaScript file myfile.js also. These series of OData calls (its more than the 5 shown below) take around 180-200 seconds to complete. This is async so, page load of Page1.htm is not affected. Also user does not come to know that these calls are happening in the background (which is a requirement to do this without asking user). But the problem is - what happens if user switches to some other page from this Page before the 180-200 seconds. I am not sure if the async tasks keep on happening in the background or will it stop in between (depending on when user moves away from Page1.htm)?

Is there a definite way this will behave or will this change depending on browser being used or some other external criteria? Please guide.

```
void MakePreferredCustomer(AccountNo)
{
    GetAccountDataFromServer() //This internally does " return Common.MakeWebApiRequest"
    .then(HandleAccountDataResponse(request){
        //Parse the response using JSON.Parse() and get account no
        //Make WebApiRequest to get more details using account no
        return Common.MakeWebApiRequest("GET", uri, additionalAccountData, headers);
    })
    .then(HandleAdditionalAccountDetails(request){
    //Parse the response using JSON.Parse() and get additional acc details
    //Store these details in additional variables in this function scope
    //Make OData call to get Product Details
    return Common.MakeWebApiRequest("GET", uri, Productdata, headers);
})
    .then(HandleProductDetails(request){
    //Parse the response using JSON.Parse() and get product details
    //Check if this account had earlier porchased this product.
    //Make OData call to get no of times this product should be purchased to become preferred customer
    return Common.MakeWebApiRequest("GET", uri, PolicyData, headers);
})  .then(HandlePolicyDetails(request){
    //Parse the response using JSON.Parse() and get policy details
    //Check No if times prodocut should be bought and how may times this account has bought
    //if condition meet, update preferred customers detials with this account as per below OData call
    Common.MakeWebApiRequest("POST", uri, ThisAccountIsNewPreferredCustomerData, headers);      
})
.catch(HandleException(e){
})
}
```

Each of the Functions call a common function MakeWebAPIRequest:

```
Common.MakeWebApiRequest = function (action, uri, data, headers)
{
//Do basci checks in input arguments
return new Promise(function (resolve, reject)
{
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(action, encodeURI(uri), true); //async call
    //Set OData specific headers using request.setRequestHeader
    request.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if (this.readyState === 4)

        {
            //Do Handling
        }
    }
    if ("POST" === action && data === "")

    {

        request.send();

    }

    else if ("GET" === action)

    {

        request.send();

    }

    else

    {

        request.send(JSON.stringify(data));

    }
});
}
```

Comment: this isn't *plain ol' javascript* is it?

Comment: @Jaromanda : Yes this is plain JavaScript file using JQuery promises. Does this answer your query?

Comment: Well. What is `void` doing there instead of `function` .. and your callbacks in .then look syntactically wrong for javascript

Comment: @Jaromanda: void came due to typescripting that was used to generate the JavaScript. Pls ignore it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user navigates away, the XMLHttpRequests will be aborted (or at least ignored on the client side), and the load handlers will be dropped and never executed. So **no**, javascript processes do not continue to work in the background.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this requirement of the calls complete (once invoked) even if pages continue to change? Any framework or approach I can use?

Comment: Not really, you cannot force the browser to do anything (what if the user shuts down his computer instead of navigating away...). If you absolutely *must* complete all of the actions, execute them on the server side. If it's just a convenience for the user (and they likely would again be executed on the next page they visit), you'll want to look at [SPAs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) and possibly [service workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)

Answer (score 0):

The async requests, once initiated, will continue. As well, the promise handlers will also get invoked and run when the dependent Promise fulfills (or is rejected).

If these processes are independent of the content on Page1.html, then you should be okay. If there is a dependency (example, when one of your promise handlers kick-off and they rely on data available within Page1) then you will have to find a way to put those dependencies within the handlers or preserve what you need through closures.

Comment: if the user navigates away from a page, there's no problem if there's a dependency - javascript code doesn't "survive" a change of page

Comment: Perhaps not clear enough. What was meant was that if there is a dependency, it may not provide the results the OP is expecting because the javascript code is no longer there and the background process may fail at that point

Comment: @Jaromanda: Am little confused. Can you explain a little more. There is no dependency on data in these 2 pages. I fact no data from the first page is also required. All data are local to the JavaScript file and the function. So will there be no problem if user navigates to different page? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @rasmeister Can you cite your claims that "*async requests will continue*" and that "*the promise handlers will also get invoked*"?

Comment: Never mind. It's to do with some wording in the answer that I misunderstood

Comment: @Bergi - when the `.then()` function is called (happens right away), it registers the handler with the Promise. So even though the script is removed a reference remains and would be invoked when the Promise fullfills (or rejects). Do you understand this to work differently?

Comment: @rasmeister Maybe the "*user moves away from Page1.htm*" is a bit unclear, but I don't think the OP refers to a simple DOM update that replaces the contents of the document with something else. Yes, in that case the js would continue running, regardless whether its source script element is still in the DOM. But when the user navigates away the browsing context, the whole environment will be destroyed, the promise will get garbage-collected and never resolved.

Comment: @Bergi - agreed. It would be like doing a refresh. Everything will be wiped.

Comment: @rasmeister: What is meant by "when the user navigates away the browsing context"? Do you mean he moves from http://www.site1.com/page1.htm to a different site http://www.site2.com, or a page refresh etc? What I meant by "user moves away from Page1.htm" is like user moving from http://www.site1.com/pahe1.htm to  www.site1.com/pahe2.htm or any other page in www.sote1.com. Does this help?